# Can i start an X session "background"?

Tags: linux, gentoo, tty, kdm

can i start the *DM (e.g. kdm) on tty7, but not present on the screen?

For example, i want to stay at tty1 while the login manager is waiting on tty7 on boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the X server not to change the vt (virtual terminal). There's an option for this: `-novtswitch`. With kdm, it should be added to the `ServerArgsLocal` line in `kdmrc`.

The bad news is that this option seems not to work in X.org (it prevents X from switching the vt when it *exits*!). Google turns up many reports, but no solution.

Depending on your needs, you may be able to get away with letting X change the vt, and then changing it back with the `chvt` command after a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks, still i'll search for it. I've heard a "no-root" patch which used by some distros.